# Странный вывод в консоль

Tags: java

```
int[] mas = new int[n];
for (int zero = 0; zero > n; n-- ) {
    for(int O=0; O < n; O++) {
        mas[O] = arr[n];
    }
    
}
System.out.println(mas);
```

Код должен брать массив arr,и перевёрнутым записывать в mas,но вывод неправильный

[I@55f96302

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mas));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот вывод правильный. Он выводит вам `hashCode` вашего массива. Это стандартное определения метода `toString()` который в свою очередь вызывается у массива когда вы вызываете `System.out.println(mas);`

Если вы хотите распечатать массив человекочитаемыми символам, вам необходимо использовать:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mas));
```

Если же в вашем массиве будут не примитивы, то вам необходимо чтоб в классах которые вы хотите распечатать был переопределен метод `toString()`, в противном случае вы просто на вывод получите список хешей.

[Здесь](http://javanese.online/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_JVM-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F/object_toString/) и [здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/) можно почитать более подробно.